# Spaces in C# Enums

Tags: c#, vb.net, enums, clr

Is there any way to put spaces in a C# enum constant?  I've read that you can do it in VB by doing this:

```
Public Enum EnumWithSpaces
  ConstantWithoutSpaces
  [Constant With Spaces]
End Enum
```

...and then access it like this:

```
Public Sub UsingEnumWithSpaces()

  Dim foo As EnumWithSpaces = EnumWithSpaces.[Constant With Spaces]

End Sub
```

That implies to me that the CLR can handle an enum with spaces.

Is there any way to do this in C#?

Comment: Related answer on another post - [Can my enums have friendly names?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1415460/465053)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This blog post might help you:

> http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/2008/01/17/associating-strings-with-enums-in-c/

From the article:

> But enums can't have spaces in C#!"
>   you say. Well, I like to use the
>   System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute
>   to add a more friendly description to
>   the enum values. The example enum can
>   be rewritten like this:

```
public enum States
{
    California,
    [Description("New Mexico")]
    NewMexico,
    [Description("New York")]
    NewYork,
    [Description("South Carolina")]
    SouthCarolina,
    Tennessee,
    Washington
}
```

Notice that I do not put descriptions on items where the `ToString()` version of that item displays just fine.

Comment: Thanks Judah for trying to clean this up for me. I was having a heck of a time trying to get it to look right.

Comment: This would be nice if ToString automatically used the attribute.  As it stands, though, it's not all that useful.

Comment: I guess you could always use the `DescriptionAttribute` along with a `ToDescription` extension method.

Comment: This method fails for the call Enum.Parse(Type enumType, string value).  The value must still be the variable name and not the description.  Which is a shame.

Answer (score 9):

CLR can handle absolutely any character in identifiers. However, C# restricts the identifier characters to those legal under the CLS, which space isn't. Same goes for VB.NET, by the way - spaces inside square brackets used to work in VB6, but they don't in VB.NET.

Comment: Is there anyway you could modify an enum constant using reflection?

Comment: Do you mean loading a compiled assembly and processing it to replace enum names, or modifying the constant at run-time? The latter is not possible; the former is, but I think it would be far simpler to use `ildasm` to disassemble it, replace the names as needed (this can be automated with regex), and use `ilasm` to make it an assembly again. Alternatively, you can declare your enum in IL in the first place, use `ilasm` to compile it to a .netmodule, and then link that module into your C#/VB assembly.

Comment: I ended up just using the `DescriptionAttribute` and then writing my own static class for accessing the enum as if the `DescriptionAttribute`s were the constants.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Visual C# 3.0 or above I've found it convenient to just extend the enum class and use a regex to inset spaces where neccessary:

```
public static class EnumExtension
{
    public static String ToDisplayString(this Enum e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"([^\^])([A-Z][a-z$])");

        return regex.Replace(e.ToString(), new MatchEvaluator(m =>
        {
            return String.Format("{0} {1}", m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);
        }));
    }
}
```

Notice this allows you to work with any enum as is without adding descriptions to every value.

```
String enumWithSpaces = MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel.ToDisplayString();
```