# Extending Enum in C#

Tags: c#, .net, enums, extension-methods

I was wondering whether or not I can extend the Enum type in C# to implement my custom Enum.GetValues(type) and call it like Enum.GetMyCustomValues(type)

I am trying to implement something like this:

```
public static bool IsFlagSet<T>(this T value, T flag) where T : Enum
{
    return (value & flag) != (T)0;
}
```

but it cannot be done...
any work arounds I can do?
Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415140/c-enums-can-my-enums-have-friendly-names

Comment: Maybe this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383974.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extensions work on instances, not for creating static methods. You can extend the base Enum using `public static void MyExtensions(this Enum value)`. But this would still only create methods on Enum instances you create. The only way to add static methods like you're talking about externally for a class is if the class is a partial class.

Edit: to do something like you want I wrote the following

```
public static bool IsFlagSet<T>(this Enum value, Enum flag)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException();
    if (value == flag) return true;
    return ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value.ToString()) &
        (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), flag.ToString())) != 0;
}
```

*warning, this method needs to be thought out more prior to use, I'm hoping there is a better way to do it.

Comment: There is not need for the generic constraint

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be looking for extension methods for enums.
Here's a starting link: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/C-Enhance-Enums-using-Extension-Methods.aspx

Comment: Not really what I am looking for, more interested in extending the Enum.SomeMethod() instead of MyCustomEnum.SomeMethod()

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20100916130304/http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/C-Enhance-Enums-using-Extension-Methods.aspx, since the link was down for me.

Answer (score 1):

And one more example.

```
    public static bool Includes<T>(this T value, T flag) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        var val = value.ToUInt32(null);
        var fl = flag.ToUInt32(null);
        return (val & fl) == fl;
    }
```

And the usage.

```
SomeEnum val = SomeEnum.One;
bool isOne = val.Includes(SomeEnum.One); // == true
bool isTwo = val.Includes(SomeEnum.Two); // == false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's test best I could think of.  Remember that enums could be based on 64 bit ints:

```
 public static bool IsFlagSet(this Enum value, Enum flag)
 {
     if (Type.GetTypeHandle(value).Value != Type.GetTypeHandle(flag).Value)
         throw new ArgumentException();
     return (Convert.ToInt64(value) & Convert.ToInt64(flag)) != 0L;
 }
```