# Can a C# enum entry have a hyphen in the name

Tags: c#, enums

Is thre any way to have an enum entry with a hyphen, "-", in the name, for example:

```
enum myEnum
{
   ok,
   not-ok,
}
```

I've seen the question about [enums having friendly names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415140/c-enums-can-my-enums-have-friendly-names) however it would save me a bit of work if I can use a hyphen directly.

Update: The reason I want to use a hyphen is it makes it easy to use an enum for lists of set values which I have no control over such as:

```
 rejected
 replaced
 local-bye
 remote-bye
```

Comment: If you are trying to split words out of the Enum value, try using CamelCase

Comment: -1 Programming languages are not by means a human language, and therefore may not understand every variation we are capable of. In any programming language I have worked with, I have never ever seen hyphens, except for the quoted identifier in TSQL or PLSQL, which allows mostly for convenient column naming convention as per the result set. CamelCase is the far netter approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can my enums have friendly names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415140/can-my-enums-have-friendly-names)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, a hyphen is not allowed.

[Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28VS.71%29.aspx)

You could obviously replace the hyphen with an underscore, but as @benPearce suggested, CamelCase would be a better choice, and in line with most C# coding standards.

Comment: I'd actually just been looking over that page. I don't knwo why they couldn't just put _ instead of Pc and a reference to the unicode doc.

Comment: I still can't find the official definition of "connector punctuations"

Answer (score 17):

Suppose you have:

```
enum E { a = 100 , a-b = 200 };
...

E b = E.a;
int c = (int)(E.a-b);
```

Is c set to 200, or 0 ?

Allowing hyphens in identifiers would make the language *almost impossible to analyze lexically*.  This language is already hard enough to analyze what with `<<` and `>>` each having two *completely* different meanings; we don't want to make it harder on ourselves.

The naming guidelines say to use CamelCasing for enum values; follow the guidelines.

Comment: I'd happily follow the guidelines but the string list the enum is needed to represent is out of my control. Lexical analysis may be hard getting half a dozen RFC's to remove hyphenated words is not easy either.

Answer (score 5):

In case somebody needs to use hyphens I think this approach can help: Use underscore in your enum declaration and then replace the underscore with hyphen.

```
enum myEnum { ok, not_ok, }

var test = myEnum.not_ok;
// let's say this value is coming from database or somewhere else
var someValue = "not-ok"; 

if(test.ToString().Replace("_","-").equals(someValue)) { /* some stuff */ }
```

Not the best practice, but can help if you don't have control over "someValue" and need to use enums.

Comment: I did something like:  Status = sqlDataReader.GetString(5).Equals("NotChecked") ? "Not Checked" : "Checked", and yeah it works (since my Enum only has two items)

Answer (score 0):

You say "I'd happily follow the guidelines but the string list the enum is needed to represent is out of my control".  Since this is why you want hyphens, I suggest you override the toString() method of the enums you need this for, and call toString() in your code where you need to represent the names.

Comment: Possible, but attributes make more sense (see the link in the question). Overriding ToString() just to get friendly names is not reasonable.