# Look up an Id and return a string value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a .NetCore 3 Entity Framework controller that returns an object like this:

```
var games = await _context.Game
   .Select(x => new GameEntity
   {
       Id = x.Id,
       Title = x.Title,
       GameCharacterClasses = x.GameCharacterClasses

    }).ToListAsync();
```

The GameEntity class looks like this:

```
public partial class GameEntity
{
    public GameEntity()
    {
        GameCharacterClasses = new HashSet<GameCharacterClasses>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GameCharacterClasses> GameCharacterClasses { get; set; }
}
```

GameCharacterClasses is an array with the Id of the game and the Id of the characterClass.

The thing is, I really need the characterClass name and not the Id of the game or characterClass.

Is there a way to make a code-based table or variable so I can look-up the needed characterClass name based on the Id?

Like, if the GameCharacterClasses array contains the Ids(GameId, CharacterClassId)

```
[(5, 1), (5, 4), (5, 7)]
```

Then the array should contain

```
'Wizard', 'Fighter', 'Cleric'?
```

I tried using a complicated if/then tree, but it got out of hand.

I'd like to have some type of look-up based variable if that's possible...like:

```
0 : Thief
1 : Wizard
2 : Paladin
3 : Assassin
 etc...
```

Is there a way to do that in c#?

Thanks!

Comment: An `enum`, a static `Dictionary<int, string>`... It depends on your use case

Comment: I like to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422407/finding-an-enum-value-by-its-description-attribute) for things like that

Comment: Why not introduce a `CharacterClass` class + table?

Comment: @GertArnold what do you mean?  I'm sorry I'm confused :)

Comment: So `CharacterClassId` is a foreign key to `CharacterClass` records that consist of Id + Name. You'll have a many-to-many relationship between `Game` and `CharacterClass`.

Comment: Does this help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions? If you use a converter you could have an enum that automagically gets converted to an int when persisted to the db and gets turned back into an enum when loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an enum named CharacterClass

```
public enum CharacterClass
{
    Thief= 0,
    Wizard= 1,
    Paladin= 2,
    Assassin= 3,
}
```

Then you will call it like this using [Enum.GetName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getname?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Enum_GetName_System_Type_System_Object_)

```
public string GetNameFromId(int charClassId)
{
    return Enum.GetName(typeof(CharacterClass), charClassId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so if I had an array with 4 Ids of CharacterClasses, I could loop through it with 'GetNameFromId' function?

Comment: Yes, assuming that you are not parsing a huge (thousands ~ millions) of ids, it should be ok this way looping it, and if using it when required. Otherwise, consider a dictionary like  Emanuel Vintilă suggested.