# Get enum value by name attribute

Tags: c#, enums

Let's say I have an enum, was wondering how can I get value Foo based provided description "Description for Foo"?

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("Description for Foo")]
    Foo,
    [Description("Description for Bar")]
    Bar
}
```

Comment: I think you can use it this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/1799401/11332666

Comment: This answers the question more directly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367723/get-enum-from-description-attribute

Comment: Rather this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422407/finding-an-enum-value-by-its-description-attribute . But note that you should cache these values in a class that has a `static Dictionary<T, string> DescriptionCache { get; }`. Enums never change at runtime, so this is a perfect candidate for caching. You don't want to use reflection any time you access your enum.