# GetCustomAttribute returns null

Tags: c#, enums, custom-attributes

Can somebody explain to me why `Value.GetType().GetCustomAttribute` returns `null`? I have looked at ten different tutorials on how to get the attributes for an enumerated type member. No matter which `GetCustomAttribute*` method I use, I get no custom attributes returned.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

public enum Foo
{
    [Bar(Name = "Bar")]
    Baz,
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class BarAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name;
}

public static class FooExtensions
{
    public static string Name(this Foo Value)
    {
        return Value.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<BarAttribute>(true).Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I should reword my question. I understand why `NullReferenceException` is thrown. What I don't understand is why `Value.GetType().GetCustomAttribute` returns `null`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because the attribute you are trying to retrieve has not been applied to the type; it has been applied to the field.

Therefore, rather than calling GetCustomAttributes on the type object, you need to call it on the FieldInfo object.  In other words, you would need to do something more like this:

```
typeof(Foo).GetField(value.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes...
```

Comment: How would I apply it to the field rather than the type?

Comment: You have applied the attribute to the feild

Comment: @TylerCrompton as Dhawalk said, in your sample code, the attribute *is* applied to the field.  That's why you're having this problem.  That's also why the attribute's own AttributeUsage attribute is for AttributeTargets.Field.  I've reworded and slightly expanded the answer.

Answer (score 2):

phoog's explanation of the problem is correct. If you want an example of how to retrieve the attribute on an enum value, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415140/c-sharp-enums-can-my-enums-have-friendly-names/1415187#1415187).

Comment: +2 the OP should definitely not have any issues understanding the code in the link provided

Answer (score 1):

your attribute is at field level, whereas `Value.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<BarAttribute>(true).Name` would return attribute applied to enum Foo

Answer (score 0):

I think you must rewrite FooExtension like this:

```
public static class FooExtensions
{
    public static string Name(this Foo Value)
    {
        string rv = string.Empty;
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = Value.GetType().GetField(Value.ToString());
        if (fieldInfo != null)
        {
            object[] customAttributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (BarAttribute), true);
            if(customAttributes.Length>0 && customAttributes[0]!=null)
            {
                BarAttribute barAttribute = customAttributes[0] as BarAttribute;
                if (barAttribute != null)
                {
                    rv = barAttribute.Name;
                }
            }
        }

        return rv;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rewriting it like this:

```
public static class FooExtensions
{
    public static string Name(this Foo Value)
    {
        var Type = Value.GetType();
        var Name = Enum.GetName(Type, Value);
        if (Name == null)
            return null;

        var Field = Type.GetField(Name);
        if (Field == null)
            return null;

        var Attr = Field.GetCustomAttribute<BarAttribute>();
        if (Attr == null)
            return null;

        return Attr.Name;
    }
}
```