# How to use DescriptionAttribute to achieve enum names with spaces?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, enums

How can I use the `DescriptionAttibute` to achieve the following with `enums`?  Note the spaces in the enum values.

```
public enum PersonGender
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        Male = 1,
        Female = 2,
        Intersex = 3,
        Indeterminate = 3,
        Non Stated = 9,
        Inadequately Described = 9
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For example you can use like that:

It is our enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   [Description("Description for Foo")]
   Foo,
   [Description("Description for Bar")]
   Bar
}
```

And our method for getting Attribute.

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    string name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
    if (name != null)
    {
        FieldInfo field = type.GetField(name);
        if (field != null)
        {
             DescriptionAttribute attr =
                    Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
                    typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
              if (attr != null)
              {
                   return attr.Description;
              }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And you can get description:

```
  MyEnum x = MyEnum.Foo;
  string description = x.GetDescription();
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415140/c-sharp-enums-can-my-enums-have-friendly-names/1415187#1415187)

Comment: I don't understand why it is so complicated to the enum description attribute.  Isn't there an in-built function to access it?

Comment: As i know there is not.