# how to display enum with set of special charaters as V1.0, V2.0 and V3.0

Tags: c#, enums

How to display enum value as V1.0, V2.0, V3.0 in C# ?

```
enum value
{
    V1.0,
    V2.0,
    V3.0
}
```

Comment: What do you mean display?

Comment: You can't use dots, try underscores instead. If you need to get a friendly description, [then check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-sharp-enum-description-from-value)

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution would be the use of the DescriptionAttribute:

```
enum value
{
    [Description("V1.0")] 
    V1_0,

    [Description("V2.0")] 
    V2_0,

    [Description("V3.0")] 
    V3_0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `.` in identifier names.

See the [C# Specification on Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx)

The best you can do would be something like:

```
enum value
{
    V1dot0,
    V2dot0,
    V3dot0
}
```

or

```
enum value
{
    V10,
    V20,
    V30
}
```

or

```
enum value
{
    V1_0,
    V2_0,
    V3_0
}
```

or use `Description` attribute like Koen suggests.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare your enum *without dots* e.g.

```
  public enum value {
    V1,
    V2,
    V3
  }
```

but you can implement *extension method* to represent enum values:

```
public static class valueExtensions {
  public static String ToReport(this value item) {
    switch (item) {
      case value.V1:
        return "V1.0";
      case value.V2:
        return "V2.0";
      case value.V3:
        return "V3.0";
      default:
        return "?"; 
    }
  }
}

...
value data = value.V1;
String result = data.ToReport(); // <- "V1.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `readonly` array :

```
public readonly string[] value={"V1.0","V2.0","V3.0"};
```

Comment: A readonly array is not immutable like an enum, readonly only stops you from re-assigning the field value, it is still possible to change the contents of the array. Also, you really shouldn't make fields public - that is what properties are for.

Comment: Probably Dictionary, not array, is better solution here: {{"V1.0", 1},  {"V2.0", 2},  {"V3.0", 3}}

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I know to do this is via descriptions like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415140/can-my-enums-have-friendly-names)

Answer (score 0):

Write a static method to display it, or encapsulate it in a class and override ToString method.

```
ToString(enumValue eValue){
switch (eValue) {
    case V10: 
       return "V1.0";
       break;
    case V20: 
       return "V2.0";
       break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign string values to an enum however you can assign using attributes. You have to associate a numeric value with a description

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace myCompany.MyProject.BO {

    public enum SampleTypes
    {
        // Default          
        [Description("- None -")]
        None=0,

        [Description("My type 1")]
        V1=1,

        [Description("My type 2")]
        V2=2,

        [Description("My type 3")]
        V3=3
    } }
```

Then you can define helper methods to get either the description or a key,value pair for binding to a dropdown list

```
  public static string GetDescription(System.Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo FieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])FieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
   if ((attributes.Length > 0))
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }

    public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetValuesAndDescription(System.Type enumType)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvPairList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        foreach (System.Enum enumValue in System.Enum.GetValues(enumType))
        {
            kvPairList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(enumValue.ToString(), GetDescription(enumValue)));
        }
        return kvPairList;
    }
```

You can bind your dropdownlists this way

```
Helpers.GetValuesAndDescription(typeof(YourEnumName));
        YourDropDown.DataValueField = "Key";
        YourDropDown.DataTextField = "Value";
        YourDropDown.DataBind();`
```

[More on this link](http://crypt-sdk.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-get-enums-and-descriptions-from.html)