# How to get values from EnumMember wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, enums, datacontract

I have WCF service with Enum as data contract. How to get list of Enum values. This is code:

in WCF

```
[DataContract]
public enum MyEnum
{
   [EnumMember(Value="My first member")]
    First,
   [EnumMember(Value="My second member")]
    Second,
   [EnumMember(Value="My third member")]
    Third
}
```

in client application:

```
Array myEnumMembers = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));

foreach(MyEnum member in myEnumMembers )
{
   MembersListBoxControl.Items.Add(member.ToString());
}
```

This works but in my list box control it shows value without space like this:

```
Myfirstmember
Mysecondmember
Mythirdmember
```

Answer (score 1):

As the values of `Enum` must [follow the same naming rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1415140/213550) as all identifiers in C#, I think this can't be done like this.

You can either use some [Resources file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296240.aspx) to store string representation or try to use a [`Description` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1415187/213550), like this:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("Description for Foo")]
    Foo,
    [Description("Description for Bar")]
    Bar
}

MyEnum x = MyEnum.Foo;
string description = x.GetDescription(); // extension method provided in original answer.
```

[MSDN article about attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx)

Comment: Not sure that this helps. I have to select enum form list so I can send it back to wcf. I can't do that whit Decription property.

Comment: @user2880783 You should add description to the TExt, and enum Value to the Value of the `ListItem`.