# C# how to retrieve a modified Enum Name value

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a real banged up API where the return values using naming conventions that are all over the place…
From camelCase to PascalCase to UPPERCASE to string with spaces… it’s a mess…

So in order to serialize or deserialize it, using json.net is simple enough adding a jsonSerializer or adding a class with json property attributes as so:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "somebanged upName")]
public string[] SomethingBangedUp;
```

I would also like to do a similar thing when hardtyping some values to an enum, and then get a list of the ‘banged up names’ rather than the variable names:

```
public enum SomeBangedUpEnum
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "someThingelse BangedUp")]
    SomethingElseBangedUp,
}

var v = Enum.GetNames(typeof(SomeBangedUpEnum)).ToList();
```

But this retrives the variable name of “SomethingElseBangedUp” and not “someThingelse BangedUp” as i hoped for;

Any idea how I can get the banged up value set by the EnumMember attribute?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1415187/5311735. Also, use something like `Description` attribute (from System.ComponentModel namespace). EnumMember is related to serialization and is completely alien here (even if it's name suggests otherwise).

Comment: This is good info... though how might i adjust said answer to retrieve all with this description attribute... (and then the normal variable names for those without any attribute)

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are metadata. If you want to read metadata, you should use reflection. You can use [GetCustomAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292(v=vs.110).aspx) extension to read attribute value from type member. E.g. if you want to get all names for enumeration members:

```
var v = typeof(SomeBangedUpEnum)
   .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static)
   .Select(f => f.GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>()?.Value)
   .ToList();
```

Or if you want to get name for some specific enum member, then instead of getting all fields you can get specific field only:

```
var name = typeof(SomeBangedUpEnum)
    .GetField(SomeBangedUpEnum.SomethingElseBangedUp.ToString())
    .GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>()?.Value;
```

Comment: why might EnumMemberAttribute not be recognized for me?

Comment: @axa you should add using for `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace as well as for `System.Reflection` namespace

Comment: All is fine but it makes little sense to use EnumMember attribute for this - it is in separate assembly, it is related to serialization, and there is no serialization here. Maybe better is to use Description attribute from System.ComponentModel. But that is nitpicking of course.

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy but i do... and i have a Reference added to the project... is this available in a later .net than 4.5.2?