# Display list of items from database based on hard coded dropdownlist selection in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display list of items from database based on `dropdownlist` selection which is hard coded in ASP.NET MVC application.

My `Controller`

```
 public ActionResult ListofItems()
            {
                ListofClassClassHandle listofClassClassHandle = new ListofClassClassHandle ();
                return View(listofClassClassHandle.LeadingAll());
            }
```

`ListofClassClassHandle` Class

```
public List<Leading> LeadingAll()
        {
            clsUtilities clsUtilities = new clsUtilities();
            DataSet ds;
            List<Leading> leading = new List<Leading>();
            string sSQL;
            sSQL = "exec GetLeading 'NZ'";
            ds = clsUtilities.GetDataSet(sSQL);
            DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
            foreach(DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                leading.Add(
                    new Leading
                    {
                        RankId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["RankId"]),
                        Name = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]),

                    }               
                    ); 
            }
```

`Leading` Class

```
public class Leading
    {
        public int RankId { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }   
        public Countries AllCountries { get; set; }

    }
public enum Countries
    {
        New_Zealand,
        Australia      
    }
```

`Leading` View

```
 @Html.DropDownList("AllCountries",
        new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Countries))),
        "Select Country",
         new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 150px;" })

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Rank")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Name")
        </th>


    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RankId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

I want to display the list based on dropdown country list selection. The dropdown list is hard coded where the list of data is populating from database.

Please guide me. I do not have any idea how to accomplish this? Any help or guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: What isn't working?  Displaying data from a database is generally covered by any tutorial.

Comment: You need to pass the selected option value of dropdown to your GET action method as a parameter and pass that to your data access method and use that when calling the stored proc. Have you tried that ?  You can keep your dropdown inside a form tag with a submit button , which can submit the form the same GET action method.

Comment: @Shyju, I have not tried this. But the dropdown list is using enum to get the countries. So how can i get the value from this one? Can you please guide me.

Comment: Ultimately it simply render a SELECT element with options. So you read the selected value and pass it to your data access method.

Comment: Posted an answer explaining how to pass the selected value to the action method code and from there to your data access method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the dropdown selection to your GET action method and from there to your data access method and use that to get the filtered set of data.

To start, add a parameter to your action method.

```
public ActionResult ListofItems(string AllCountries="")
{
    var h = new ListofClassClassHandle();
    return View(h.LeadingAll(AllCountries));
}
```

And update the `LeadingAll` method to accept this parameter. Update your data access code to  use the value inside the `country` variable.

```
public List<Leading> LeadingAll(string country)
{
    // to do : use the value of country to call the stored procedure
    // to do : return list of Leading objects
}
```

Now in your View, you can keep your dropdown list inside a `form` tag along with  a submit button. Set the form tag's action attribute value to your `ListOfItems` action method and set the form `method` attribute to `GET`.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ListOfItems", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("AllCountries",
            new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Countries))),
            "Select Country",
            new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 150px;" })
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
}
```

When the user selects an option from the SELECT element and click submit button it will make a GET call with the selection in the querystring ( Ex :`/ListOfItems/?AllCountries=Australia`) and your action method code will use this value to get the data for that country by passing that to your data access method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. I will try this and will see how it works. If i stuck anywhere then I will let you know. Thank you once again.

Comment: Shyju, Sorry to interrupt you. Can you please guide me how to get value from Enum. As from database, the value is coming like "NZ" for New Zealand, "AUS" for Australia. As you can see this code sSQL = "exec GetLeading 'NZ'". Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: No. You cannot do that with enum (straight out of the box). There are some workarounds where you can use the Description attribute and use LINQ to get the description and value and use that to build the dropdown. Your other option is to fix the data in the table or the enums so that the data match. Or keep some sort mapping ( a dictionary) which maps NewZeland to NZ and use that to get the code before calling the stored proc. Or Use a Country table and store the CountryId in your other table.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415140/can-my-enums-have-friendly-names

Comment: Shyju, I removed Enum from the Leading class and added all the countries in View.  @using (Html.BeginForm("ListOfItems", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <select class="form-control" id="Countries" >
             <option selected="selected" value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
                <option value="AUS">Australia</option>               
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
        } Please guide me now how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: How to do what ? If your options have the same value as your data in the table, you are good. When you submit the form, the query string will have that (option value, `NZ` or `AZ`) and you need to update your other code to use that value to get the filtered data as i mentioned in the answer.'

Comment: Shyju, Can you please guide me how to grab option value from View and use that value into  this class. Please guide me. I am stuck here. public List<Leading> LeadingAll(string country)
{
   
}

Comment: That is exactly what i have in the answer. You have to do a form submit and you will have the selected option value in your action method parameter. Read the answer carefully

Comment: Shyju, I did what you said to me. But string AllCountries=" " is blank. This is the code @using (Html.BeginForm("ListOfItems", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) { <select class="form-control" id="Countries" > <option selected="selected" value="NZ">New Zealand</option> <option value="AUS">Australia</option> </select> <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> } . Whenever i select country, it is passing null there.

Comment: Your select element should have a name attribute with value `AllCountries` `<SELECT name='AllCountries'></SELECT>`

Comment: Shyju, Thank you so much. It worked for me now.