# C# How do i remove underscore for enums? So that it displays as United Kingdom instead of United_Kingdom

Tags: c#

```
 public class PizzaIngredient
 {

     public enum Country
     {
        SouthKorea,
        United_Kingdom,
        united_States
     }
 }
```

Comment: `UnitedKingdom` .. Probably

Comment: The problem with that is space between, United_Kingdom should be United Kingdom on the front end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the under score from the definition :

```
public enum Country
{
    SouthKorea,
    UnitedKingdom,
    UnitedStates
}
```

or if that is not possible add descriptors to the enum , example here : [Can my enums have friendly names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415140/can-my-enums-have-friendly-names)