# Replace PSObj property value based on a list

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I've the following PSObj with some properties stored in an $array :

```
ComputerName      : MyComputer
Time              : 08/11/2022 13:57:53
DetectionFile     : MyBadFile.exe
ThreatName        : WS.Reputation.1
Action            : 12
```

I'm trying to replace the action ID number by it's corresponding description. I've a hashtable with the possibles reasons behind the Action ID

```
$ActionId = @{
    0  = 'Unknown'
    1  = 'Blocked'
    2  = 'Allowed'
    3  = 'No Action'
    4  = 'Logged'
    5  = 'Command Script Run'
    6  = 'Corrected'
    7  = 'Partially Corrected'
    8  = 'Uncorrected'
    10 = 'Delayed   Requires reboot to finish the operation.'
    11 = 'Deleted'
    12 = 'Quarantined'
    13 = 'Restored'
    14 = 'Detected'
    15 = 'Exonerated    No longer suspicious (re-scored).'
    16 = 'Tagged    Marked with extended attributes.'
}
```

I'm trying to parse each item of this array, and each value of the reason ID to replace the ID by the reason string

```
    # parse array
    foreach ($Item in $array) {
        # parse possible values
        foreach ($value in $ActionId) {
            if ($value -eq $item.Action) {
                $Item.Action = $ActionId[$value]
                $Item.Action
            }
        }
```

From my understanding, I'm missing the correct syntax here

```
$Item.Action = $ActionId[$value]
```

I do not get any errors, but from the debugger, I'm replacing the action property by $null with the above...

Comment: Actually the issue still remains, and couldn't find an answer from the other similar ones. I'm still trying to replace the value but I can't adress the "$ActionId[$value]" part seems wrong as it still replaces the value by $null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate fix is to **loop over the *keys***  (`.Keys`) of your `$ActionId` [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables):

```bash
foreach ($Item in $array) {
  # parse possible values
  foreach ($value in $ActionId.Keys) {
      if ($value -eq $item.Action) {
          $Item.Action = $ActionId[$value]
          $Item.Action  # diagnostic output
      }
  }
}
```

Note:

- To avoid confusion, consider renaming `$value` to `$key`.
- Generally, note that **hashtables are *not* enumerated in the pipeline / in looping constructs in PowerShell**.

  - That is, `foreach ($value in $ActionId) ...` doesn't actually loop over the hashtable's entries, and is the same as `$value = $ActionID`)
  - If you want to enumerate a hashtable's *entries* - as key-value pairs of type [`System.RuntimeType`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.RuntimeType) - you would need to use the `.GetEnumerator()` method; in your case, however, enumerating the *keys* is sufficient.

---

However, the simpler and more efficient solution is to **test whether the `$Item.Action` value exists as a key in your hashtable**, using the latter's [`.Contains()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable.Contains) method:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
foreach ($Item in $array) {
  if ($ActionId.Contains($Item.Action)) {
    $Item.Action = $ActionId[$Item.Action]
    $Item.Action  # diagnostic output
  }
}
```

---

You can **further streamline** this as follows, though it is conceptually a bit obscure:

```bash
foreach ($Item in $array) {
  if ($null -ne ($value = $ActionId[$Item.Action])) {
    $Item.Action = $value
    $Item.Action  # diagnostic output
  }
}
```

- `=` is only ever PowerShell's *assignment* operator; for equality / non-equality *comparison*, `-eq` / `-ne` is required.
- Here, an assignment to `$value` is indeed being performed and the *assigned value* then acts as the RHS of the `-ne` operation; in other words: you can use assignment *as expressions* in PowerShell.
- If hashtable `$ActionId` has *no* key with value `$Item.Action`, `$ActionId[$Item.Action]` quietly returns `$null`.

---

Finally - in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) only - an **even more concise** (though not necessarily faster) solution is possible, using **`??`, the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#null-coalescing-operator-)**:

```bash
foreach ($Item in $array) {
  $Item.Action = $ActionId[$Item.Action] ?? $Item.Action
  $Item.Action # diagnostic output
}
```

That is, the value of `$ActionId[$Item.Action]` is only used *if it isn't `$null`*; otherwise, `$Item.Action`, i.e. the current value, is used (which is effectively a no-op).

---

<sup>[1] `.ContainsKey()` works too, and while this name is conceptually clearer than `.Contains()`, it is unfortunately not supported by PowerShell's `[ordered]` hashtables ([`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary)) and, generally speaking, not supported by other dictionary (hashtable-like types), given that the [`System.Collections.IDictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionary) interface only has `.Contains()`</sup>

Comment: Very detailed explanation thank you ! I tried noth methods out of curiousity, and assume that the 2nd one is more efficient as it's not parsing both array & hashlist.
For the record, looks like your 2nd method always returns $null. From my debugger :


`[DBG]: PS C:\\Scripts> $ActionId[12]`  
`Quarantined`  
`[DBG]: PS C:\\Scripts> $Item.action`  
`1`  
`[DBG]: PS C:\\Scripts> $ActionId[$Item.action]`  
`\\ nothing`

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Douda; my pleasure. I'm not sure what you mean re the 2nd method - from what I can tell, all solutions work the same.

Answer (score 3):

In addition **[mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)**'s helpful answer, I was just thinking outside the box (aka question):
This is typical situation where I would consider to use an [`enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum) except for the fact that that the keys do not (easily) accept spaces (as in your question).

```
Enum ActionTypes {
    Unknown
    Blocked
    Allowed
    NoAction
    Logged
    CommandScriptRun
    Corrected
    PartiallyCorrected
    Uncorrected
    Delayed
    Deleted
    Quarantined
    Restored
    Detected
    Exonerated
    Tagged
}

$PSObj = [PSCustomObject]@{
    ComputerName      = 'MyComputer'
    Time              = [DateTime]'08/11/2022 13:57:53'
    DetectionFile     = 'MyBadFile.exe'
    ThreatName        = 'WS.Reputation.1'
    Action            = 12
}
$PSObj.Action = [ActionTypes]$PSObj.Action
$PSObj

ComputerName  : MyComputer
Time          : 8/11/2022 1:57:53 PM
DetectionFile : MyBadFile.exe
ThreatName    : WS.Reputation.1
Action        : Restored
```

The advantage is that you won't lose the actual action id, meaning if you e.g. insert the object back into a database, it will automatically type cast to the original integer type:

```
$PSObj.Action
Restored
[int]$PSObj.Action
12
```

Comment: Thank you iRon ! Never used enum, yet. I'll definitely have a look

Comment: That's a nice alternative, if the names can be represented as identifiers (which excludes not only spaces, but any character other than digits, letters, and `_`). Just to clarify, when you say "not easily", I assume you're referring to decorating members with _attributes_, such as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1415187/45375, correct? Or were you thinking of somehow _encoding_ non-allowed characters, which would require later decoding?

Comment: @mklement0, thanks, I was indeed looking into that so answer but did not have the time to figure it out how to do this in PowerShell. Maybe later this weekend... I think the best translation is "**aka**" (changed)