# C# Enum return string with breaks

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I need my enum to return a specific string, but I can't work out how to make it return a string with breaks in it without having a method to do the conversion.  Is it possible to make `LicenseTypes.DISCOUNT_EARLY_ADOPTER` return `DISCOUNT EARLY-ADOPTER` without the helper method?

```
// All license types
public enum LicenseTypes
{
    DISCOUNT,
    DISCOUNT_EARLY_ADOPTER,
    COMMERCIAL,
    COMMERCIAL_EARLY_ADOPTER
}

// Convert enum to correct string
public static string LicenseTypeToString(LicenseTypes Enum)
{
    if (Enum == LicenseTypes.COMMERCIAL)
        return "COMMERCIAL";
    else if (Enum == LicenseTypes.COMMERCIAL_EARLY_ADOPTER)
        return "COMMERCIAL EARLY-ADOPTER";
    else if (Enum == LicenseTypes.DISCOUNT)
        return "DISCOUNT";
    else if (Enum == LicenseTypes.DISCOUNT_EARLY_ADOPTER)
        return "DISCOUNT EARLY-ADOPTER";
    else
        return "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a string with breaks?

Comment: @Bolt, I mean it returns the string "DISCOUNT EARLY-ADOPTER" which has the space gap in it, the enum doesn't like spaces so I have to underscore them

Comment: Have you seen this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117542/spaces-in-c-enums) that talks about using System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute to create better enum descriptions with spaces?

Comment: As much as you might hate it, I actually don't think there's really anything particularly wrong with your simple helper method approach. I'd only suggest using a `switch` statement instead of a bunch of `if`/`else` blocks, as the compiler can do a better job optimizing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, a separate option from a helper method is simply to have a `Dictionary<LicenseTypes, string>` which you populate once. That would probably be the simplest approach, to be honest:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<LicenseTypes, string> LicenseDesciptions =
    new Dictionary<LicenseTypes, string> 
{
    { LicenseTypes.COMMERCIAL, "COMMERCIAL" },
    { LicenseTypes.COMMERCIAL_EARLY_ADOPTER, "COMMERCIAL EARLY-ADOPTER" },
    { LicenseTypes.DOMESTIC, "DOMESTIC" },
    { LicenseTypes.DOMESTIC_EARLY_ADOPTER, "DOMESTIC EARLY-ADOPTER" },
};
```

(As noted in comments, another alternative is a switch/case... but I personally prefer this way, as effectively you've got a *data* mapping, so it makes sense to use a *data* structure rather than an *execution flow* structure. It also means you can swap out dictionaries for different languages etc if you want.)

Secondly, one option would be to decorate each enum value with a `[Description]` attribute (or your own attribute if you want), and find that out with reflection - [Unconstrained Melody](http://unconstrained-melody.googlecode.com) has an extension method which can do that very easily:

```
// Throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException if the licenseType value isn't defined
// or doesn't have a description.
string description = licenseType.GetDescription();
```

Also, following .NET naming conventions it should be:

```
public enum LicenseType // Singular as it's not a Flags enum
{
    Discount,
    DiscountEarlyAdopter,
    Commercial,
    CommercialEarlyAdopter
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon!  Great answer, also I bought your book the other week and am going to start getting in to it, seems brilliant!

Comment: +1: I like your argument for using a data structure for a data mapping.

Comment: @Tom: Cool - hope you enjoy the book. Ping me if anything doesn't make sense :)

Answer (score 2):

A little reflection, and Attribute magic, and this should just answer it :)
[Getting attributes of Enum's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value)

Might also make it an [extension method](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/c-enhance-enums-using-extension-methods.aspx).

here's how it should look (also added generics):

```
public static class MyExtensionsClass
{
    public static string ToDescriptionString<T>(this T val)
        where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsEnum) 
        {
           var type = val.GetType();
           var memInfo = type.GetMember(val.ToString());
           var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
           return ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
        }
        return ""; //all paths must return a value
    }
}

public enum LicenseTypes
{
    [Description("DISCOUNT")]
    DISCOUNT,
    [Description("DISCOUNT EARLY-ADOPTER")]
    DISCOUNT_EARLY_ADOPTER,
    [Description("COMMERCIAL")]
    COMMERCIAL,
    [Description("COMMERCIAL EARLY-ADOPTER")]
    COMMERCIAL_EARLY_ADOPTER
}
```

Thank you, guys that wrote these:

- [Enhance enums using extension methods](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/c-enhance-enums-using-extension-methods.aspx)
- [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't eliminate the helper method, note that in your case you *could* just special-case the values that you can't get using `ToString`:

```
switch (Enum) {
    case LicenseTypes.COMMERCIAL_EARLY_ADOPTER:
        return "COMMERCIAL EARLY-ADOPTER";
    case LicenseTypes.DISCOUNT_EARLY_ADOPTER:
        return "DISCOUNT EARLY-ADOPTER";
    default
        return Enum.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this from Google's dotnet client - [StringValueAttribute.cs](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis/Apis/Util/StringValueAttribute.cs)
and [Utilities.cs](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis/Apis/Util/Utilities.cs)

```
public enum LicenseType
{
     [StringValue("DISCOUNT")] Discount,
     [StringValue("DISCOUNT EARLY-ADOPTER")] DiscountEarlyAdopter,
     [StringValue("COMMERCIAL")] Commercial,
     [StringValue("COMMERCIAL EARLY-ADOPTER")] CommercialEarlyAdopter
}
```

Then you can simply do this:

```
licenseType.GetStringValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to string using "G" format, then replace "_" (underscore) with spaces:

```
LicensceTypes license = LicenseTypes.COMMERCIAL_EARLY_ADOPTERS;
string licenseDescription = license.ToString("G").Replace('_', ' ');
// licenseDescription = "COMMERCIAL EARLY ADOPTERS"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's hard to maintain if we add other licenses in the future which have underscores etc!

Comment: This leaves out the OP's desired hyphen (`-`), though.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use a class to avoid this scenario. :/

```
public class LicenceType
{
    private string name;
    public LicenceType(string Name)
    {
        this.name = Name;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}

public static class LicenceTypes
{
    public static LicenceType DISCOUNT = new LicenceType("DISCOUNT");
    public static LicenceType DISCOUNT_EARLY_ADOPTER= new LicenceType("DISCOUNT EARLY-ADOPTER");
    public static LicenceType COMMERCIAL= new LicenceType("COMMERCIAL");
    public static LicenceType COMMERCIAL_EARLY_ADOPTER= new LicenceType("COMMERCIAL EARLY-ADOPTER");
}
```